# Will there be employers from many countries?

Tags: discussion, jobs, demographics

In jobs.stackoverflow.com most of the jobs are from USA and UK. Will careers.stackoverflow.com have similar employers locations?

What is being done to encourage employers from other countries to use this site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is intended to be a worldwide service, and all of our location fields are fully world-aware, so yes.

As to how many there *will* be, I cannot say, but it is our intention to be worldwide.

(with the inevitable caveat that we have no immediate plans to localize the UI)

update: employer search stats now available:

[image]

Comment: Does "localize" mean *just* translating languages/times?  No problemo.    But what about the 'granularity' issues with city/whatever/country categorization?  That is very much make or break, in my blunt opinion, as to whether or not CSO will be viable outside US/Canada, and maybe the UK.

Comment: Will you post locations at some point> This would encourage candidates from those area. I guess this discourage those from outside then in turn discourage employers though?

Comment: What Stu said. In the UK, I can either enter towns (much too local) or England (much too broad). You need to have at least counties (which mean something here!) or regions. Best of all would be a time-based distance from a point, so e.g. 90 minutes from NW1 3AP; that's hard, I know, so alternatively a distance such as 60 miles from E14 9RK might also work.