# CSO : Display countries/cities of employers

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs, location

Considering all discussions on SO and CSO are in english, it might be interesting, on CSO, to display some kind of map showing where employers are from -- and/or where they want to recruit.

I'm thinking about something like a google map with a marker for each employer, which would be visible without having to file a CV -- not displaying too much informations, of course ; just country/city would be quite nice, actually.

It would allow users that are not from the US/UK to know if careers could be interesting for them, before putting their CV online *(ie, there is no point in paying to file a CV if there is no employer from our non-US country)*.

There is already the possibility for us to indicate where we want to work -- this would be exactly the same thing, indicating where employers are recruiting.

Comment: +1 Absolutely, there should be some way for job-seekers to see how many employers there are from a given area. (Related questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25246/is-careers-going-to-be-worth-it-for-canadians, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24988/will-there-be-employers-from-many-countries)

Comment: likewise for skill set in a given area, e.g .net/c# in Cambridge UK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We now have **public employer search statistics** for CV holders, under the stats tab -- just click "show detail>>" to expand.

This list is queried dynamically about every hour, and reflects current live data.

[image]

(we may also enhance this to show a map of every query in lat/long as well)

Comment: Thanks !  (bouh, not a single query for France ;-( ) ;; and thanks for the "top tags", too : being able to see what recruiters are searching for is nice too !

Answer (score 3):

Ultimately it's a chicken-and-egg problem.  Employers will only be interested if there is a robust pool of CV's, and applicants will only be interested if there are enough employers in the system to make it worth the money.

Judging by the track record of J & J, I have no doubt that this has been beaten to death internally and that they'll come through it to lead the pack.  I imagine the $29 initial offering is supposed to go a long way to solve the problem, and it probably will - but it would definitely be more attractive to us peons if we knew what the picture looked like locally.

Comment: hopefully there will be a large pool of initial applicants who don't mind relocating : )