# Is Careers going to be worth it for Canadians?

Tags: discussion, jobs, location

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CSO : Display countries/cities of employers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25055/cso-display-countries-cities-of-employers)

I've searched for jobs within 500 miles of where I live on jobs.stackoverflow.com, and I get at the most, three jobs.  None for where I live.

What's the appeal to pay money if there aren't any Canadian companies using careers?  Will it be possible for us to see how many employers are using the system in our region, or will it basically be gambling $100 to be seen by potentially nobody, and we have no way of knowing? (No answers about moving to the states to pursue opportunities please ;)

Comment: +1 for "Will it be possible for us to see how many employers are using the system in our region". If I ever were to use the service, I'd be *very* interested in that too (albeit from a European perspective).

Comment: I think it's odd that a search that includes both the Seattle and Portland areas (not to mention Vancouver) comes up with only three tech jobs.

Comment: It comes up with one in Surrey, one in Seattle and one in Portland.  I guess the concern is just that if we're more interested in pursuing local or regional opportunities, rather than moving cross country, there's currently very little way to determine the value of the $99.

Comment: I'm on board with this question too; I want to know if there's any point in filing my CV, if the only people who will see it are hiring managers > 1500km away from me.

Comment: Well, it's only gambling 29$ for the next 10 days, if that's any consolation...

Comment: There's also a 90 day money back guarantee... so at least we should get to check out the employers.  Very nice.  I ended up buying.

Answer (score 6):

We on the Stack Overflow team love Canada!

http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/3167/kissedcanadianflag.png

See? Proof.

Comment: Are those pony lips?

Comment: Wait, I know! They're moose lips.

Comment: The field behind the maple leaf is supposed to be **white**, not grey. Likewise for the **red** colours. Did you dip our flag in dirty water before kissing it?

Answer (score 4):

Just an update to using Careers from the Canadian perspective.

More than six months into the service, it's not looking to be very valuable for me.  Out of 8500+ searches, I've had 56 "hits" and 8 views.

I'm not willing to relocate, which is probably pretty big, but I'm guessing that being in Canada is by far the overriding factor.  It would really be nice to see the number of employers in Canada that are actively using Careers.

Answer (score 4):

Yeah, this is pretty much a total fail for me, but almost all the employers I've seen on Careers are in Toronto or Vancouver.

Here are my stats:

```
354 Total Employers
8225 Total Searches
21 Search Hits on Your CV
116 Public Views of Your CV
1 Employer Views of Your CV
0 Email Inquiries to You from Employers
0 Email Responses from You to Employers
```

I knew I was gambling with the money; it didn't pay off. Oh well.

Comment: thanks for the update; you can expect lots of pushing on this from the NYC team over the next year, though

Answer (score 1):

I've just done a search of the listings; the ones in Canada are mostly in two tech hubs, Toronto and Vancouver, neither of which are useful to me. The site appears to be US-centric...not that that's bad, but not too useful for me.

Admittedly, Vancouver's not terribly far away, but far enough to require relocation. I'm happy living where I am now, so I will stick to more local resources.