# Number of employers looking in a particular city

Tags: feature-request, jobs

Is there a simple way to determine the number of employers looking to hire developers in a particular city or state?

I want to determine if it is worth my while (and money) to "file" my resume. I live in Melbourne, Australia, so the number of employers looking at 
careers.stackoverflow.com will be fairly low. I want to quantify this.

If you live in one of the major US centres of software development (Seattle, SF etc) you can be confident there will be plenty of employers in your area. In more remote parts of the globe this won't necessarily be the case.

Comment: very little exposure in aussie, even in syd at the moment

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31285/can-we-see-the-count-of-relevant-employers-on-our-careers-page, and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25055/cso-display-countries-cities-of-employers, and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25246/is-careers-going-to-be-worth-it-for-canadians.  There is a lot of resistance to this unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We now have **public employer search statistics** for CV holders, under the stats tab -- just click "show detail>>" to expand.

This list is queried dynamically about every hour, and reflects current live data.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Looks like a great enhancement.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be good to know the geographical spread of employers (or more precisely the location of the vacancies those employers are looking to fill). Whilst this may prevent people from paying to file their CV in the first place, the no-quibble money back guarantee already means that people could get their money back if they are not happy with the employer locations once they have paid (albeit with more hassle).

Instead of a list of employers and their locations, perhaps it could be similar to the employer search UI, where you specify a location and by moving the slider you can see how many vacancies there are within a distance to the specified location.

I know there is the outlook that you should put your CV on careers and then "*forget*" about it until contacted by an employer, but if I was spending money to file my CV, I'd like to know it would be money well spent before doing so.

Answer (score -1):

Even if there's only 1 employer, 99$ aren't that much considered that you can get a new, awesome job.

Comment: There's no guarantee it'll be awesome. Melbourne isn't exactly known for its 'awesome' software industry.

Comment: It's a straight cost-benefit equation. If there is only one employer looking to hire in Melbourne then the odds of getting a good job through this site are low. I just want a bit more visibility.