# Statistics on careers searches by country

Tags: support, jobs, statistics

I think I remember reading somewhere a list of countries ordered by number of searches, such as:

- United States: 25,000 searches/day
- United Kingdom: 8,000 searches/day
- Canada: 1,000 searches/day
- France: 60 searches/day

(Numbers are made up; this is just an example)

Now I can't find it anymore. Is this information still available somewhere? I don't remember whether it was a post on meta or a dynamic page on the website.

Comment: I'm not sure if what you're looking for is what I have in my (deleted) answer, because that's all I can find. Maybe you're remembering what it looked like on one of the initial revisions before it was officially released?

Comment: @Jon: see Jeff's answer =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See:

[CSO : Display countries/cities of employers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25055/cso-display-countries-cities-of-employers/34885#34885)

[image]

Comment: Thank you =) Looks like London is first for now!